# Does $L$ having a real form imply that $L_{\mathbb C}\simeq L\oplus L$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

Assume we are given a complex Lie algebra $L$ having a real form. That is, there is a real Lie algebra $g$ which has a complexification $g_\mathbb{C}\cong L$.

I have seen several examples where the following holds, but is $L_\mathbb{C}\cong L\oplus L$ always true in this situation?

Comment: Are you sure that you are asking what you want to ask? I ask this because, since $L$ is a complex Lie algebra, $L_{\mathbb C}$ is $L$ itself.

Comment: Yes, you first forget the $\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}$-action of $L$ and then built $L_\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: You should perhaps write the tensor products more explicitly to remove the confusion, and write $g\otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C}$ and $L\otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C}$ to make it clear that you are first restricting $L$ to $\mathbb{R}$ before extending it to $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 1):

For clarity, I denote by $Res_{\mathbb C\vert \mathbb R}A$ the scalar restriction of a complex Lie algebra $A$ to $\mathbb R$, i.e. $A$ viewed as real Lie algebra.

If $L \simeq g \otimes_{\mathbb R} \mathbb C$, then there are isomorphisms
$$ (Res_{\mathbb C\vert \mathbb R}L) \otimes_{\mathbb R} \mathbb C \simeq Res_{\mathbb C\vert \mathbb R} (g \otimes_{\mathbb R} \mathbb C) \otimes_{\mathbb R} \mathbb C \simeq g \otimes_{\mathbb R} (\mathbb C \otimes_{\mathbb R} \mathbb C) \stackrel{!}\simeq g \otimes_{\mathbb R} (\mathbb C \oplus\mathbb C) \simeq (g \otimes_{\mathbb R} \mathbb C) \oplus (g \otimes_{\mathbb R} \mathbb C) \simeq L \oplus L$$

of $\mathbb C$-Lie algebras (complex scalars always acting on the right here). The crucial step uses

$$\mathbb C \otimes_{\mathbb R} \mathbb C \stackrel{!}\simeq \mathbb C \oplus\mathbb C$$

as $(\mathbb R, \mathbb C)$-modules.

---

Note that in general for a field extension $E \vert K$ of degree $n$ and an $E$-Lie algebra $L$, one has an obvious map

$$ (Res_{E\vert K}L) \otimes_{K} E \simeq (Res_{E\vert K} L) \otimes_{K} K^n  \simeq \underbrace{(Res_{E\vert K}L) \oplus \dots \oplus (Res_{E\vert K}L)}_{n}$$

but only as $K$-Lie algebras, as such maps (just given by choosing a $K$-basis of $E$) are not $E$-linear unless in trivial cases, and are different from the map above.

As for a concrete counterexample in case $L$ has no real form, I do not know, but I suspect already the easiest cases of such Lie algebras (which would be solvable three-dimensional) would give counterexamples.